# What is equivalent of smooth(t,ECG_signal,0.1,'rloess') in python?

Tags: python, matlab, signal-processing, loess

What is python equivalent of this code to remove baseline wandering. It is using the local polynomial regression smoother (LOESS).

```
t = 1:length(ECG_signal);
yy2 = smooth(t,ECG_signal,0.1,'rloess');
BWRemoveDataFile = (ECG_signal-yy2);
```

I tried this but it is not working.

```
    frac = 0.1

    # Create a time vector t
    t = np.arange(len(ECG_signal))
    # Apply loess smoothing to the ECG data
    lowess = sm.nonparametric.lowess(ECG_signal, t, frac=frac)

    # Extract the smoothed values
    smoothed_ecg = lowess[:, 1]

    # Remove baseline wander from the signal
    BWRemoveDataFile = ECG_signal - smoothed_ecg
```

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67713973/4601890)?